# Activiti : Last completed task

Tags: sql, activiti, bpmn

**Problem**

I want to get the last task completed for the process instance. I am able to get the last completed `human task`, but not a `Service task`.

**What i have tried**

I have written a `SQL` query, i am using `MySQL`, to find out what is last task that is completed. Here it goes :

```
SELECT * FROM act_hi_taskinst 
where PROC_INST_ID_= '1234' and END_TIME_ IS  NOT NULL
order by END_TIME_ desc;
```

`act_hi_taskinst` is the table that gets updated as and when the process instance progresses.

The process flow goes something like this :

A human Task (`Leave request`) -> Service task( `Check availability` of leave) -> service task(`Check feasibility`) -> A human task(`Manager task`)

When the task comes to `Manager Task` the last completed is `Check feasibility`, but its not reflecting in database.

**Can you please help**

Does activiti provide any such API to get the last completed `service task`? Can you suggest some `SQL query` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for is stored in `act_hi_actinst` table. It contains information about every activity that’s being executed as part of a process instance.

```
SELECT * FROM act_hi_actinst WHERE proc_inst_id_ = '1929' 
AND end_time_ IS NOT NULL ORDER BY end_time_ DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @ATMTA, i appreciate it. I found that couple of hours back.